# NGINX drop connection when 502 error

Tags: node.js, nginx

I need for NGINX to drop the connection (i.e. don't reply) which I believe is error 444 when there is a bad gateway 502 error using nodejs proxy.

The reason is we have remote clients deployed remotely across several countries that has code that looks for a no response from server and runs some javascript code that waits for the page to come alive again.

I **cannot** change the code on the clients and so need NGINX to not reply if the nodejs server is down instead of replying with 502 bad gateway, this is not best practice I know but it is the problem that needs solving.

Here's my location config:

```
location / {

  if (-f $document_root/error502.html) {
    return 444;
  }

  proxy_pass http://localhost:800; 
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; 
  proxy_buffering off; 
}
```

This is not working and I am looking for help in solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
location / {
  error_page 502 =444 /444-response
  ...
}

location = /444-response {
  return 444;
}
```